# The value of $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(a+3h)-3\sin(a+2h)+3\sin(a+h)-\sin a}{h^3}$ is?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Here was my approach: I grouped the terms $\frac{\sin(a+3h)-\sin a}{h^3} $ and $\frac{3\sin(a+h)-3\sin(a+2h)}{h^3}$. By using first principle and got $\frac{3\cos a-3\cos(a+h)}{h^2}$. However, now when I expand $\cos(a+h)$ using the identity, my final answer isn't quite right. The answer is supposed to be $-\cos a$. I cannot understand where I went wrong so please help me with this.

Comment: Assuming that your calculus are correct, does a ratio of $(f(a+h) - f(a))/h$ look familiar to you ?

Comment: That is what I tried to do with the grouping

Comment: I mean, if you take the limit when $h$ tends to $0$, does it look like something that you might have defined in class ?

Comment: Hint: with compound angle formulae you can reduce the problem to finding the limits of two functions of $h$ only; one, which would otherwise be a $\sin a$ coefficient, is $0$.

Comment: The problem with the grouping is that $\frac{\sin(a+3h)-\sin{a}}{h^3}$ diverges, so you can't apply the principle that the limit of sum equals sum of limits. Applying L'Hôpital's Rule 3 times to the entire expression works (if you keep track of factors carefully ;-) ).

Answer (score 4):

$\lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(a+3h)-3\sin(a+2h)+3\sin(a+h)-\sin a}{h^3}\\
\lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(a+3h)-\sin(a+2h)-2\sin(a+2h)+2\sin(a+h) + \sin(a+h)-\sin a}{h^3}$

From the definition of the derivative
$\lim_\limits{h\to 0} \frac {\sin(a+h) - \sin a}{h} = \frac {d}{dx} \sin a = \cos a$

Similarly

$\lim_\limits{h\to 0} \frac {\sin(a+2h) - \sin (a+h)}{h} = \frac {d}{dx} \sin (a+h) = \cos (a+h)$
and
$\lim_\limits{h\to 0} \frac {\sin(a+3h) - \sin (a+2h)}{h} = \frac {d}{dx} \sin (a+2h) = \cos (a+2h)$

$\lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac{\cos(a+2h)-2\cos(a+h)+\cos a}{h^2}$

Doing a similar trick...

$\lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac{\cos(a+2h)-\cos(a+h) -\cos(a+h) +\cos a}{h^2}\\
\lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac{-\sin(a+h)+\sin(a)}{h} = -\cos a$

Comment: user317176, you did not calculate the limits correctly. For example 
$$\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin(a\!+\!2h)\!-\!\sin(a\!+\!h)}h =\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{2\cos\left(\!a\!+\!\frac{3h}2\!\right)\sin\left(\frac h2\right)}h=$$
$$=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\left[\cos\left(\!a\!+\!\frac{3h}2\!\right)\dfrac{\sin\left(\frac h2\right)}{\frac h2}\right]=\cos a\cdot1=\cos a$$but you wrote the limit is $\,\cos(a+h)\,.\;$Analogously, it results that $$\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin(a\!+\!3h)\!-\!\sin(a\!+\!2h)}h=\cos a$$but you wrote $\,\cos(a+2h)\,.\;$ Also you didn’t calculate correctly the other limits.

Comment: Moreover, $\;\dfrac{\sin(a\!+\!2h)\!-\!\sin(a\!+\!h)}h\sim \cos\left(\!a\!+\!\frac{3h}2\!\right)\;$ as $\;h\to0\;$ but you calculated the limit as if $\;\dfrac{\sin(a\!+\!2h)\!-\!\sin(a\!+\!h)}h\sim \cos\left(a\!+\!h\right)\;.$ Also the other parts of your answer are not right. Por example ,  $\;\dfrac{\sin(a\!+\!3h)\!-\!\sin(a\!+\!2h)}h\sim \cos\left(\!a\!+\!\frac{5h}2\!\right)\;$ as $\;h\to0\;$ but you calculated the limit as if $\;\dfrac{\sin(a\!+\!3h)\!-\!\sin(a\!+\!2h)}h\sim \cos\left(a\!+\!2h\right)\;.$

Comment: @Angelo you might notice that we arrive at the same answer.  I did take one shortcut along the way, but the the math is fine.  The more important fact is $f'''(x) = \lim_\limits{h\to 0} \frac {f{x+3h} - 3f(x+2h) + 3f(x+h) - f(x)}{h^3}$ which would not be clear using your method.

Comment: Correct method leads to a correct answer, but it is false that a method is correct if it leads to a correct answer. Moreover it is absolutely wrong that $$\lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(a+2h)-\sin (a+h)}{h}=\frac d{dx}\sin (a+h)$$   
and  
$$\lim_\limits{h\to 0} \frac {\sin(a+3h) - \sin (a+2h)}{h} = \frac {d}{dx} \sin (a+2h)$$Actually the result of both limits is $\cos a$. In the case that you meant to get an equivalent function as $h\to0$, it is wrong that $\dfrac {\sin(a+2h)-\sin (a+h)}{h}\sim\cos (a+h)$, in fact it is $\sim\cos\left(a+\frac{3h}2\right).$

Comment: Try to use an application that shows the graph of that functions and you will see the mistake.

Comment: Note that for any function $f$ differentiable at $x=a$ it results that $$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(a+mh)-f(a+nh)}h=(m-n)f’(a)$$ In particular, if $m=n+1$, the result of the previous limit is $f’(a)$, not $f’(a+\text{something}\!\cdot\!h)$.

Comment: Look at the following Taylor expansions:$$\sin(a+h)=\sin a+h\cos a-\dfrac12h^2\sin a+o(h^2)$$
$$\sin(a+2h)=\sin a+2h\cos a-2h^2\sin a+o(h^2)$$
Consequently ,$$\dfrac{\sin(a+2h)-\sin(a+h)}h=\cos a-\dfrac32h\sin a+o(h)$$
which is not equivalent to
$$\cos(a+h)=\cos a-h\sin a+o(h)$$
but it is equivalent to
$$\cos\left(a+\dfrac{3h}2\right)=\cos a-\dfrac32h\sin a+o(h)$$

Comment: @Angelo I could have started with  $\lim_\limits{h\to 0} \frac {\sin(a+3h) - 3\sin(a+2h) + 3\sin(a+h) -\sin(a)}{h^3} =  
\lim_\limits{h_1\to 0} \lim_\limits{h_2\to 0} \lim_\limits{h_3\to 0} \frac {\sin(a+h_1+h_2+h_3) - \sin(a+h_1+h_2) - 2\sin(a+h_2+h_3)  + 3\sin(a+h_3) -\sin(a)}{h_1h_2h_3}$ and it would resolve exactly as above.  But, really don't think that that is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [sum-to-product formulas](https://trigonometrywithereza.wordpress.com/sum-to-product-and-product-to-sum/) .

$\sin(a\!+\!3h)\!-\!3\sin(a\!+\!2h)\!+\!3\sin(a\!+\!h)\!-\!\sin a=$

$=\sin(a\!+\!3h)\!-\!\sin(a\!+\!2h)\!-\!2\big[\sin(a\!+\!2h)\!-\!\sin(a\!+\!h)\big]\!+\\\quad+\sin(a\!+\!h)\!-\!\sin a=$

$=2\cos\left(\!a\!+\!\dfrac{5h}2\!\right)\!\sin\left(\!\dfrac h2\!\right)\!-\!4\cos\left(\!a\!+\!\dfrac{3h}2\!\right)\!\sin\left(\!\dfrac h2\!\right)\!+\\\quad+2\cos\left(\!a\!+\!\dfrac h2\!\right)\!\sin\left(\!\dfrac h2\!\right)=$

$\!\!=2\sin\left(\!\dfrac h2\!\right)\!\!\left[\cos\left(\!a\!+\!\dfrac{5h}2\!\right)\!\!-\!2\cos\left(\!a\!+\!\dfrac{3h}2\!\right)\!\!+\!\cos\left(\!a\!+\!\dfrac h2\!\right)\right]\!=$

$=2\sin\left(\!\dfrac h2\!\right)\!\!\left[\cos\left(\!a\!+\!\dfrac{5h}2\!\right)\!-\!\cos\left(\!a\!+\!\dfrac{3h}2\!\right)\!-\!\cos\left(\!a\!+\!\dfrac{3h}2\!\right)\!+\\\quad+\cos\left(\!a\!+\!\dfrac h2\!\right)\right]\!=$

$\!\!\!\!\!=2\sin\left(\!\dfrac h2\!\right)\!\!\left[-2\sin\left(a\!+\!2h\right)\sin\left(\!\dfrac h2\!\right)\!\!+\!2\sin\left(a\!+\!h\right)\sin\left(\!\dfrac h2\!\right)\right]\!=$

$=-4\sin^2\!\!\left(\!\dfrac h2\!\right)\!\!\bigg[\sin\left(a\!+\!2h\right)\!-\!\sin\left(a\!+\!h\right)\bigg]\!=$

$=-8\sin^2\!\!\left(\!\dfrac h2\!\right)\!\cos\left(\!a\!+\!\dfrac{3h}2\!\right)\!\sin\left(\!\dfrac h2\!\right)=$

$=-8\sin^3\!\!\left(\!\dfrac h2\!\right)\!\cos\left(\!a\!+\!\dfrac{3h}2\!\right)\,.$

Consequently ,

$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\sin(a+3h)-3\sin(a+2h)+3\sin(a+h)-\sin a}{h^3}=$

$=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{-8\sin^3\!\!\left(\frac h2\right)\cos\left(a\!+\!\frac{3h}2\right)}{h^3}=$

$=-\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\sin^3\!\!\left(\frac h2\right)\cos\left(a\!+\!\frac{3h}2\right)}{\left(\frac h2\right)^3}=$

$=-\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\left[\dfrac{\sin\!\left(\frac h2\right)} {\frac h2}\right]^3\!\!\!\cos\left(a\!+\!\frac{3h}2\right)=-1^3\!\cdot\cos a=$

$=-\cos a\;.$

Answer (score 3):

I unsuccessfully attempted to brute force the limit by expanding all of the terms using the angle addition identity for sine. Instead, using [L'Hôpital's Rule](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html) three times produces the same result,

$$ \begin{align}
L &=\tag{1}\lim_{h \to 0} \left[\frac{\sin(a + 3h) - 3\sin(a + 2h) + 3\sin(a + h) - \sin a}{h^3} \right] \\
&=\tag{2} \lim_{h \to 0} \left[\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}h}[\sin(a + 3h) - 3\sin(a + 2h) + 3\sin(a + h) - \sin a]}{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}h}[h^3]} \right] \\
&=\tag{3}\lim_{h \to 0} \left[\frac{3\cos(a + 3h) - 6\cos(a + 2h) + 3\cos(a + h)}{3h^2} \right] \\
&=\tag{4}\lim_{h \to 0} \left[\frac{\cos(a + 3h) - 2\cos(a + 2h) + \cos(a + h)}{h^2} \right] \\
&=\tag{5}\lim_{h \to 0} \left[\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}h}[\cos(a + 3h) - 2\cos(a + 2h) + \cos(a + h)]}{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}h}[h^2]} \right] \\
&=\tag{6}\lim_{h \to 0} \left[\frac{-3\sin(a + 3h) - 4\sin(a + 2h) - \sin(a + h)}{2h} \right] \\
&=\tag{7}\lim_{h \to 0} \left[\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}h}[-3\sin(a + 3h) - 4\sin(a + 2h) - \sin(a + h)]}{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}h}[2h]} \right] \\
&=\tag{8}\lim_{h \to 0} \left[\frac{-9\cos(a + 3h) + 8\cos(a + 2h) - \cos(a + h)}{2} \right] \\
&=\tag{9} \frac{1}{2} \lim_{h \to 0} \left[-9\cos(a + 3h) + 8\cos(a + 2h) - \cos(a + h) \right] \\
&=\tag{10} \frac{1}{2} (-9 \cos a + 8 \cos a - \cos a) \\
&=\tag{11} \frac{1}{2} (-2 \cos a) \\
&=\tag{12} \boxed{-\cos a}
\end{align}$$

L'Hôpital's was used in steps $(2)$-$(3)$, $(5)$-$(6)$, and $(7)$-$(8)$.